# how to install python-webkit and python-webkit-dev in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

I was getting E: Package 'python-webkit' has no installation candidate

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-50:~$ sudo apt install python-webkit 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-webkit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-webkit' has no installation candidate
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-50:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

And run `sudo apt-get update`